# How to properly split a String input of a filename using the split()?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am creating an ImageViewer application which prompts the user using `showInputDialog` to first input the name of the first image filename. However, I got stuck splitting the `String` by using the `split()`. Say for example the user inputs **image1.gif**  and I have to make sure that I can split them into three elements. Firstly will be **image** followed by **1** and finally **gif**. So do you guys think you can help me with it? Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    //First input dialog. Example from user will be like:  image1.gif
    String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input name of first image file");
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(userInput);
    String a = userInput.split(".");
    String fileName = myScanner.next();
    String fileNumber = myScanner.next();
    String fileFormat = myScanner.next();
}
```

Here's the trial part. But it says that the Array index is out of bound exception. Any advise?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class TestImageViewer {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    //First input dialog. Example from user will be like:  image1.gif
    String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input name of first image file");
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(userInput);
    String[] a = userInput.split(".");


    System.out.println(a[0]);

}
}
```

Comment: You could start by reading the docs for `String#split(...)`  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Since you're not just splitting on some sort of delimiter (that is, since you want the "1" as its own token as well), you're probably better off using regular expressions and captured groups for this.  Do you know that your input is always going to be of the form <name><index>.<extension>?

Comment: I will edit my answer in response to your edits

Comment: You probably meant `split("\\.")`.  The regular expression "." refers to any character, so you will not be splitting the file name into period-delimited parts as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you split to must be returned to an array to store all the sections of the String that is split. So, like this:

`String[] a = userInput.split(".");`

`a[0]` will hold **Image1** and `a[1]` will hold **gif** in this example. Knowing this, you can then get the letters from the first index of the array like this:

`String number = a[0].replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");`

and the numbers like:

`String letter = a[0].replaceAll("[0-9.]", "");`

These are Regex functions, which may be good to look into to understand a little more.

EDIT: In response to OP's edits, I guess I didn't put my code in context. Here's the full code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    //First input dialog. Example from user will be like:  image1.gif
    String directions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input name of first image file");

    // System.in will set up the scanner to read user input from the keyboard. 
    // myScanner.next() will grab the first "token" (a section of text without spaces) from this input
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create variables to store name, number and extension
    String letters, number, ext;
    String fileName = myScanner.next();
    if (fileName.indexOf(".") > -1) {
        String[] a = userInput.split(".");
        letter = a[0].replaceAll("[0-9.]", "");
        number = a[0].replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
        ext = a[1];
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem like you grasp some basics about using the `Scanner` class in Java. Hopefully this helps, but try to look at other examples.

Comment: hey thanks for guiding me over here! I tried with your first line of code first just to make sure it works for the array but it doesn't. Could you have a look at it as i will edit it now? Cheers!

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 this is because the string you're trying to split (in this case `userInput`) doesn't have a "." - you hardcoded it to be "Please input name of first image file" . You should have your scanner call the `next()` method once, and then try and parse that string. Perhaps you should check for the existence of a dot beforehand, like `if (userInput.indexOf(".") > -1)`

Comment: hey thanks mate for showing your efforts. oh yeah i've just started learning not long ago so I'm kinda weak on tat right now but gradually from you guys' teachings, I can confirm i learnt much more faster. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a regular expression and a `Matcher` for more flexibility over the pattern of your input file:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("image1.gif");
if(matcher.find()) {
    String fileName = matcher.group(1);
    String fileNumber = matcher.group(2);
    String fileFormat = matcher.group(3);
}
```

`(.+)(\\d+)\\.(.+)` denotes a pattern consisting of one or more characters, followed by one or more digit, then a dot, and finally one or more word characters that represent the file extension. Each of these are captured in groups inside parentheses.

`matcher.group(1)` returns `image` matched by `(.+)`

`matcher.group(2)` returns `1` matched by `(\\d+)`

`matcher.group(3)` returns `gif` matched by `(\\w+)`

Answer (score 1):

`split` returns an array with the different sections of the string. So if you use `.` as the delimiter, you will at least need to provide an array that will be set by your call to `split`. Second, you may want to try an alternate way of finding `fileNumber` as your files don't seem to be formatted as **image.1.gif**.